# how to display the database in my admin page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

after i submit the form , it can send all the data to the sql database.
and now , what i wan to do is display all the database data in the admin page

here is my php form code

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateButton(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      }

  }
</script>
        <title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form1.css"/>

</head>

<title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form1.css"/>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">

<?php 

//define variable and set to empty value

$forenameErr = $surnameErr = $emailErr = $postalAddressErr = $landLineTelNoErr = $mobileTelNoErr = $sendMethodErr = $checkErr ="";
$valid = true;

// if forename is null , make it null , else test_input()
$forename = empty($_POST["forename"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["forename"]);

// if surname is null , make it null , else test_input()
$surname =  empty($_POST["surname"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["surname"]);

// if postalAddress is null , make it null , else test_input()
$postalAddress = empty($_POST["postalAddress"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["postalAddress"]);

// if landLineTelNo is null , make it null , else test_input()
$landLineTelNo = empty($_POST["landLineTelNo"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["landLineTelNo"]);

// if mobileTelNo is null , make it null , else test_input()
$mobileTelNo = empty($_POST["mobileTelNo"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["mobileTelNo"]);

//email
$email = empty($_POST["email"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["email"]);

// if sendMethod is null , make it null , else test_input()
$sendMethod = empty($_POST["sendMethod"]) ? NULL : test_input($_POST["sendMethod"]);

//check
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

    if  (isset($_POST["submit"])){


        //check forename
        if($forename === NULL)  {
            //forename is empty
            $forenameErr = "*Forename is required";
            $valid = false;

        } else {
            //check characters
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$forename)) {
                 $forenameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                 $valid = false;
             }
        }

        //check surname
        if($surname === NULL){
            //surname is empty
            $surnameErr = "*Surname is required";
             $valid = false; //false

        } else {
            //check charaters
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$surname)) {
             $surnameErr = "*Only letters and white space allowed";
             $valid = false;
            }
        }   

         //check address
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\\,. ]*$/", $postalAddress)) {
                     // check characters
                     $postalAddressErr = "*Invalid Postal Address";
                     $valid = false;//false
        }


            // check if invalid telephone number added
            if (!preg_match("/^$|^[0-9]{12}$/",$landLineTelNo)) {
                //check number
                     $landLineTelNoErr = "*Only 12 digit number can be entered";
                     $valid = false;//false
            }


            //check valid mobiel tel no
            if (!preg_match("/^$|^[0-9]{11}$/",$mobileTelNo)) {
                //check number
                     $mobileTelNoErr = "*Only 11 digit number can be entered";
                     $valid = false;//false
            }


        //check valid email
            if (isset($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
            { $emailErr = "*Invalid email format"; 
                 $valid = false;//false
             }


        //check sendMethod
        if($sendMethod === NULL){
             //send method is empty
             $sendMethodErr = "*Contact method is required";
             $valid = false; //false
        } else {
            $sendMethod = test_input($_POST["sendMethod"]);
        }

        //sendmethod link to information filled
        if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="email" && $email ==NULL){
            $emailErr ="*Email is required ";
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="post" && $postalAddress ==NULL){
            $postalAddressErr ="*Postal Address is required ";
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="SMS" && $mobileTelNo ==NULL){
            $mobileTelNoErr ="*Mobile number is required ";
            $valid = false;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['agree']) || $_POST['agree'] != 'agree') {
        $checkErr ="Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy";
        }


    //Sever side script
    if($valid){

    /* SQL code starts */

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chollerton");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if (is_null($_POST["email"]) || $_POST["email"]=="") {
         $email = 'NULL';
         } else {
             $email = ($_POST["email"]);
             }

    if (is_null($_POST["postalAddress"]) || $_POST["postalAddress"]=="") {
         $postalAddress = 'NULL';
         } else {
             $postalAddress = ($_POST["postalAddress"]);
             }

    if (is_null($_POST["landLineTelNo"]) || $_POST["landLineTelNo"]=="") {
         $landLineTelNo = 'NULL';
         } else {
             $landLineTelNo = ($_POST["landLineTelNo"]);
             }  

    if (is_null($_POST["mobileTelNo"]) || $_POST["mobileTelNo"]=="") {
         $mobileTelNo = 'NULL';
         } else {
             $mobileTelNo = ($_POST["mobileTelNo"]);
             }  


    $sql   = $sql = "INSERT INTO ct_expressedinterest (forename, surname, email, postalAddress, landLineTelNo, mobileTelNo ,sendMethod) VALUES ('$forename', '$surname', '$email', '$postalAddress', '$landLineTelNo', '$mobileTelNo' ,'$sendMethod')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));


     //if valid then redirect
    if($valid){

         $_SESSION['forename'] = $forename;
         $_SESSION['surname'] = $surname;
         $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
         $_SESSION['postalAddress'] = $postalAddress;
         $_SESSION['landLineTelNo'] = $landLineTelNo;
         $_SESSION['mobileTelNo'] = $mobileTelNo;
         $_SESSION['sendMethod'] = $sendMethod;

         header('Location: userdetail.php');
         exit();
        }else    {echo "Unable to insert";
        }
    }   else{
         //user did not submit form!
    }


    }
?>


<div id="wrapper">

<h1>Welcome to Chollerton Tearoom! </h1>

<nav> 
    <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="findoutmore.html">Find out more</a></li>
         <li><a href="offer.html">Offer</a></li>
         <li><a href="credit.html">Credit</a></li>
         <li><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
         <li><a href="wireframe.html">WireFrame</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<form id ="userdetail" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">

    <fieldset id="aboutyou">
    <legend id="legendauto">user information</legend>

        <p>
        <label for="forename">Forename: </label>
        <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" value="<?php echo $forename;?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $forenameErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?php echo $surname;?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $surnameErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="postalAddress">Postal Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="postalAddress" id="postalAddress" value="<?php echo $postalAddress;?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $postalAddressErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="landLineTelNo">Landline Telephone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="landLineTelNo" id="landLineTelNo" value="<?php echo $landLineTelNo;?>" >
        <span class="error">  <?php echo $landLineTelNoErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="mobileTelNo">Moblie:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobileTelNo" id="mobileTelNo" value="<?php echo $mobileTelNo;?>" >
        <span class="error">  <?php echo $mobileTelNoErr;?></span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error"> </span> <?php echo $emailErr;?> </span>
        </p>

        <fieldset id="future">
        <legend>Lastest news</legend>

        <p>
        Choose the method you recommanded to recevive the lastest information
        </p>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sendMethod"  <?php if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="email") echo "checked";?>  value="email">
        Email
        <input type="radio" name="sendMethod"  <?php if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="post") echo "checked";?>  value="post">
        Post
        <input type="radio" name="sendMethod"  <?php if (isset($sendMethod) && $sendMethod=="SMS") echo "checked";?>  value="SMS">
        SMS
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $sendMethodErr;?></span>
        </fieldset>

       <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

         <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)">  
         I Agree Terms & Coditions
         <br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">


     </fieldset>
</form>      

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my admin.php code

```
    <?php
    include 'database_conn.php'; //make db conncection

    $sql = "SELECT expressInterestID, forename, surname, email, postalAddress, landLineTelNo, mobileTelNo ,sendMethod FROM ct_expressedinterest";

    $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn,$$sql) or die(mysql_error($conn));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
         $expressInterestID = $row['expressInterestID'];
         $forename = $row['forename'];
         $surname = $row['surname'];
         $email = $row['email'];
         $postalAddress = $row['postalAddress'];
         $landLineTelNo = $row['landLineTelNo'];
         $mobileTelNo  = $row['mobileTelNo'];
         $sendMethod = $row['sendMethod'];

         echo"<div> $expressInterestID , $forename, $surname, $email,$postalAddress, $landLineTelNo, $mobileTelNo, $sendMethod </div>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($queryresult);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

this admin.php is include to connect to the chollerton database.
here is the database_conn that connect to the table

```
<?php 
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chollerton");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else {echo "conect success";}
?>
```

can some one pls tell me what's wrong with my code??
the admin page cnt display the data in the database.
please help me and provide solution code for me...
thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

There are problem into your `admin.php` code. You use `mysqli_query($conn,$$sql)` instead of `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)`.

Try this code:

```
<?php
include 'database_conn.php'; //make db conncection

$sql = "SELECT expressInterestID, forename, surname, email, postalAddress, landLineTelNo, mobileTelNo ,sendMethod FROM ct_expressedinterest";

$queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
    $expressInterestID = $row['expressInterestID'];
    $forename = $row['forename'];
    $surname = $row['surname'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $postalAddress = $row['postalAddress'];
    $landLineTelNo = $row['landLineTelNo'];
    $mobileTelNo  = $row['mobileTelNo'];
    $sendMethod = $row['sendMethod'];

    echo"<div> $expressInterestID , $forename, $surname, $email,$postalAddress, $landLineTelNo, $mobileTelNo, $sendMethod </div>";
}

mysqli_free_result($queryresult);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: thank you Sir!!! <br>
just a typo and i didnt saw it <br>
spent almost 2 hour on this.....
Appreciate it!!